# Google Analytics: How can I set Event /Goal tracking for popup text?

Tags: google-analytics, popup, event-tracking, goal-tracking

usually I track event by button click:

> ```
> onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'PDF', 'Príbehy úspešnej liečby detí'])
> ```

Now I would like to measure with Google Analytics when text popup -> **if someone fill out form a text will popup and when the text will popup I wanna measure an *Event* or *Goal***. How can I do it? What tracking code should I insert to popup text?

Comment: Define "when text popup" -- also, u don't have to use native event handlers (ie. onclick) to push events to GA, you could push it while/when you're "popping up the text"

Comment: the popup shows after a user fill out a form and click button SEND (I can not use event for button). Here is the popup part:`<div class="alert alert-success"><?php _e('Formulár bol úspešne odoslaný. Ďakujeme za otázku budeme vás kontaktovať.', 'slovak') ?></div> `Yes I believe there is another method. Can you show me an example?

Comment: _gaq.push...... is used in classic analytics, you should really switch to universal, which uses ga(send,..... Make sure you update your tracking code too though.

Comment: I do not have rights to switch to universal GA. Can you show me an example, how should I use classic GA?

Comment: Sure, you can show me how to track it with Universal GA.

Comment: maybe this can be ok,           `  <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-33080453-1');
            pageTracker._trackEvent("registration", "iCBC", "Registracia do iCBC");
            pageTracker._trackPageview();
           });
          </script>`
but when I tested it, I havent seen any real-time events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shold be just like this. I shold think 4 times before I ask.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'PDF', 'Príbehy úspešnej liečby detí'])
</script>
```